Correct email validations in PHP laravel Livewire
I want to validate emails correctly , the correct email must adhere to the following validation rules
(a) email must end with either .com , .gov , got , co , .uk , etc
(b)email must be unique
public $email = '';
    
        protected $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email|min:3|unique:subscribers,email|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/',
        ];
    
        protected $messages = [
            'email.required' => 'The email field is required.',
            'email.email' => 'Please provide a valid email address.',
            'email.unique' => 'This email is already subscribed.',
            'email.regex' => 'The email must be a valid format (e.g., must include ".com").',
        ];
    
        public function updated($propertyName)
        {
            $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
        }
    
        public function submit()
        {
            $validated = $this->validate();
    
            // Save the email to the subscribers table
            Subscriber::create(['email' => $this->email]);
    
            // Send email
            Mail::to($this->email)->send(new SubscriptionMail($this->email));
    
            $this->reset();
            session()->flash('success', 'You have subscribed successfully!');
        }
   

the codes above does not work ,

What have you tried to address the issue? The regex provided will allow any domain, regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}, so change the regex accordingly? Furthermore why would you only want to allow .com?

"the correct email must end with .com" - where's the code for this requirement? Do you want to check this through PHP or through JS?

@NicoHaase - See the $rules array

@DarkBee how can i allow more than .com? such as .got , .gov .co ,.uk

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

have you tried validating what the emails end with:
protected $allowedDomains = [
  '.com', '.gov', '.got', '.co', '.uk'
];

protected $rules = [
  'email' => 'required|email|min:3|unique:subscribers,email|ends_with:'.implode(',',$this->allowedDomains),
];

